# Tautology - First Order Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I have a question in my exam practice, to determine if the following statement is a tautology, in First Order Logic:

[image: question]

I think it is a tautology, but am I correct?

In my course the proffesor told us to "translate" the statement to Propositional Logic, like that:

[image: second]

Your help is appriciated, is the statment above a tautology in first order logic?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the first-order formula $\forall x (p(x) \rightarrow p(x))$ is *valid* and we can obtain it "generalizing" an *instance* of the tautology : $\varphi \rightarrow \varphi$.

I.e. we can obtain it from the tautology $\varphi \rightarrow \varphi$ replacing $\varphi$ with the formula $p(x)$.

Regarding $\forall x p(x) \lor \lnot \forall y p(y)$, it is obtained from $\varphi \lor \lnot \psi$, which is not a tautology.

But it is also a *valid* formula of first-order logic; in fact, it is equivalent to $\forall x p(x) \lor \lnot \forall x p(x)$ which is obtained from the tautology $\varphi \lor \lnot \varphi$.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought, I don't know why the answer the proffesor gave me is not the same.

Comment: But according to 'A Mathematical Introduction to Logic' by Enderton 2nd edition page 115, there is this sentence 'On the other hand, neither $\forall x (Px \rightarrow Px)$ nor $\forall x Px \rightarrow Px$' is a tautology'.